# Html Local Storage Not inputting correctly

Tags: jquery, html

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.levelsSaved = 1;
$('#button1').click() {
    levelsSaved = [1, 2]
}

function checkLevels() {
    localStorage.savedLevels = JSON.stringify(levelsSaved);
    if (localStorage.savedLevels == [1, 2]) {
        $('#button2').show();
    }
  }
});
```

**PROBLEM:**

The problem with the code is when you go to the local Storage(f12).

It already has it set to [1,2] without even clicking the button, the button is just a place holder for when you complete level one the next button will appear it's level 2.

It will appear using `.show()` but when you refresh I want the Level two button to stay there and not hide.

Thank you please take a look at the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6L16556/3/) it includes greater detail of the code like html and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify([1, 2])` gives us `"[1,2]"`. If you then compare that to an array, you cause the array's `toString` to be called. `Array#toString` just does `Array#join`, which will give you `"1,2"` (note the lack of `[]`). So the comparison will never be true.

If you want to compare them, and they're always going to be simple numbers, you could use `JSON.stringify` on your array and compare the strings; or if they're going to be at all more complex than that, you'll want to use any of several array comparison algorithms.

Gratuitous strings example:

```js
var items = [1, 2];
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // [1,2]
snippet.log(String(items));         // 1,2
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

It's not at all clear from your question why you want an array at all, but here's an example of how you can store and retrieve an array using local storage: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/quqivu/1) *(Stack Snippets disallow local storage, so the live copy is over on JSBin)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    // Get the array from local storage. If we've never stored
    // an array before, `localStorage.theArray` will be
    // `undefined`, so we use || "[]" to parse a blank array.
    var theArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.theArray || "[]");

    // Show its contents
    showArray("Array from local storage:", theArray);

    // Add a random number to the end
    theArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));

    // Save the array
    localStorage.theArray = JSON.stringify(theArray);

    // Show what we saved to local storage
    showArray("Array we saved to local storage:", theArray);

    display("Now hit refresh and you'll see the stored copy has the number we added.");

    function showArray(msg, a) {
      display(msg + " (" + a.length + ")");
      a.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        display(index + ": " + entry);
      });
    }

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Oriol: Sure enough, I thought the default used the space, but a quick test says no. Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Im really new at using html storage and I don't really understand some of the things that you said, such as '    snippet.log    '

Comment: @NicholasAyoub: `snippet.log` just writes text to the output of a Stack Snippet, it's nothing to do with local storage or anything other than putting runnable code here on SO. The point is that you're comparing the result of `JSON.stringify` with an array, and they'll never match.

Comment: Could you show me an example that would help in my case, I fixed up the errors you told  me about, but nothing worked. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e6L16556/4/ I fixed it up but still nothing I even changed the JSON.stringify. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @NicholasAyoub: I've added an example of using local storage to save and retrieve an array.

Comment: I've decided to change it up and use a highest level type thing. Here is my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/e6L16556/5/ ,  when you click the button 1 it changes the value to Two and when you refresh it stays 2 so that works but the button two does not appear? @T.J.Crowder